# Updating javascript variable on html page through html button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic program where the user is shown a current room temperature along with a text field and "Set" button so that they can set their desired room temperature. What I want to happen is when the user enters a number into the text field and hits the Set button it changes the "roomTemp" variable to their desired temperature also known as "desiredTemp" and displays it as the current temperature. I don't think it's reaching the save() function as nothing is printed in my console when the button is clicked when it should output "Temperature is changing!" to my console.

Javascript File:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var roomTemp = 20;
var desiredTemp = 0;

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  //since we are in a request handler function
  //we're using readFile instead of readFileSync
  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('error occurred');
      return;
    }

    var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {roomTemp: roomTemp});  //get redered HTML code
    res.end(renderedHtml);
  });
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server Running at http://127.0.0.1:3000  CNTL-C to quit');
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Thermostat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Current Temp: <%= roomTemp %> <br></br>

<form>
Desired Room Temperature: <input type="number" id="desTemp" name="roomTempDes"><br></br>
<button onclick="save(document.getElementById("roomTempDes").value)">Set</button>
</form>

<script>
function save(desiredTemp) {
      roomTemp = desiredTemp;
      console.log("Temperature is changing!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FWIW, you may want to look into something like KnockoutJS/AngularJS and use a bi-directional model. Then it's simply a matter of assigning to `model.temperature` and the UI changes.

Comment: Here's an example of KnockoutJS: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbnzpyjt/ Check your console to see the update event trigger as you change the temperature.

Comment: Okay that could work but it has to change with the button click, not as the textfield value changes. I'll see if I can get that to work!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbnzpyjt/1/

Comment: I'm using node.js to run the server, I believe I have everything ready to go but it's giving me an error 
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'build/output/knockout-latest.debug.js'

Comment: KnockoutJS doesn't need to run on the server, only on the front-end webpage (unless I'm misunderstanding the question?).

Comment: It works perfectly in fiddle but it's not working on the webpage through my server. Do I have to include anything in my html to import knockout?

Comment: Just the knockout js file, and include it before defining your model and binding it.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many quotation marks in your script.

```
"save(document.getElementById("roomTempDes").value)"
```

should be

```
"save(document.getElementById('roomTempDes').value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quoted incorrectly **AND** you have the WRONG ID.

```
<button onclick="save(document.getElementById('desTemp').value)">Set</button>
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed that. I'm still getting nothing :/